# LINQ Query with both CASE statement and SUM function

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sum, case

I'm struggling to find an example of how to return a conditional sum using a LINQ query or LAMBDA.  I've written both independently but combining the CASE with SUM is vexing.   I'm tempted to "cheat" and use a SQL view, but thought I'd ask first.  I greatly appreciate any suggestions.  Here's my SQL that I'm looking to convert.

```
SELECT     p.product_name, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN o.order_dt <= getdate() - 1 THEN o.quantity END) AS volume_1day, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN o.order_dt <= getdate() - 7 THEN o.quantity END) AS volume_7day, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN o.order_dt <= getdate() - 30 THEN o.quantity END) AS volume_30day, 
           SUM(o.quantity) AS volume_all
FROM       products p left outer join orders o on p.product_id = o.product_id
GROUP BY   p.product_name
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example using the Northwinds database. This will get you the results that you are expecting but the SQL won't match your example.

```
using (var context = new NorthwindEntities())
{
    DateTime volumn1Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
    DateTime volumn7Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
    DateTime volumn30Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);

    var query = from o in context.Order_Details
                group o by o.Product.ProductName into g
                select new
                {
                    ProductName = g.Key,
                    Volume1Day = g.Where(d => d.Order.OrderDate.Value <= volumn1Date)
                                  // cast to Int32? because if no records are found the result will be a null                                              
                                  .Sum(d => (Int32?) d.Quantity),
                    Volume7Day = g.Where(d => d.Order.OrderDate.Value <= volumn7Date)
                                  .Sum(d => (Int32?) d.Quantity),
                    Volume30Day = g.Where(d => d.Order.OrderDate.Value <= volumn30Date)
                                   .Sum(d => (Int32?) d.Quantity)
                };


    var list = query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

### answer does not wrong but does not generate optimize query. better answer is:

```
using (var context = new NorthwindEntities())
{
    DateTime volumn1Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
    DateTime volumn7Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
    DateTime volumn30Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);

var query = from o in context.Order_Details
                group o by o.Product.ProductName into g
                select new
                {
                    ProductName = g.Key,
                    Volume1Day = g.Sum(d => d.Order.OrderDate.Value <= volumn1Date ? (Int32?) d.Quantity : 0),
                    Volume7Day = g.Sum(d => d.Order.OrderDate.Value <= volumn7Date ? (Int32?) d.Quantity : 0),
                    Volume30Day = g.Sum(d => d.Order.OrderDate.Value <= volumn30Date ? (Int32?) d.Quantity : 0)
                };

    var list = query.ToList();
}
```