# how to convert SQL query containing CASE WHEN statement to linq query in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

Here i am attaching the sql query to convert. Please help me to convert the below SQL query to linq query.

```
SELECT st.Product_Id, pr.Product_Name , st.UoM_Id, u.UoM_Name , w.Warehouse_Name
            ,SUM(st.Quantity) AS Total_Stock
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN st.Stock_Type_Id= 1 THEN st.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Primary Stock'
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN st.Stock_Type_Id= 2 THEN st.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Online Sales'
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN st.Stock_Type_Id= 3 THEN st.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Showroom Sales'
        FROM [ML_W_Stock] AS st
         INNER JOIN [ML_Warehouse] AS w ON st.Warehouse_Id = w.Warehouse_Id
         INNER JOIN [ML_Product] AS pr ON st.Product_Id = pr.Product_Id
         INNER JOIN [ML_UoM] AS u ON st.Uom_Id = u.UoM_Id
         INNER JOIN [ML_Stock_Type] tp ON st.Stock_Type_Id=tp.Stock_Type_Id 
         WHERE st.Warehouse_Id =  @Warehouse_Id
         GROUP BY st.Product_Id, pr.Product_Name , st.UoM_Id , u.UoM_Name , ST.Warehouse_Id,w.Warehouse_Name
         ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ Query with both CASE statement and SUM function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562882/linq-query-with-both-case-statement-and-sum-function)

Comment: What you need to do is create an [Enum](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dinesh.kulkarni/2007/11/05/linq-to-sql-tips-1-how-to-map-an-enum/) and you "case" will automatically interpreted by linq and auto mapping. Do it with the right way.