# How to convert CASE Sql query to Linq?

Tags: sql, linq

I have case statement in my SQL query, i need to convert the same in LinQ statement. I am getting error while converting. Please help.

```
sum(case when [Filter1].[engagement_phase_id2] = 5 then 1 else 0 end) ClientEngagementPhase,
```

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936028/linq-case-statement. There is no direct correspondent, but you can use ternary operator

Comment: Have a look at [LINQ Query with both CASE statement and SUM function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4563122/5519709)